# how to create a shape like this

Tags: java, box2d, shapes

I'm new in programing Java and I want to learn more. I hear about `libgdx` and `box2d`, and I want to play a bit with them, I want to create a field with an object that changes the gravity when the screen is touched. My problem is the field, I want to implement something like this:

[image: Shape I want to create]

But I don't know how this shape is called, to look over the internet, and how I should keep in memory this shape...

Can you give me some advices and examples, please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shapes like those are called "Spline"s. There are several different kinds of those.

In Box2D terms you would create a Body with an Edge-Fixture and Box2D will then keep this shape itself, once it was created in the World.

I think you are probably trying to achieve some kind of "ground". So you might want to check out this article: http://www.iforce2d.net/blog/2013-07-20

Comment: another noob question :( how to create a simple Spline in Box2d.. my poor google search didint find any example

Comment: @RareșSmeu As I said, the equivalent of a Spline would be an Edge Fixture. A Spline doesn't exist in Box2D you can only aproximate it. That means you will need to step through your nice, curvy Spline and use discrete coordinates to approximate the curve via an edge. LibGDX has also three different spline implementations which you can use to do so. You give the Spline some base vertices, to define how it should look like and then step (let's say every 10 pixels) through the spline in X direction to calculate the Y value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ChainShape** class in *Box2D* (or *JBox2D*).
Please take a look at this great resource:
http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-5-physics-libraries/

There is a part of using ChainShape class along with Vec2's which define Chain's points.

[image: chainshape example]